# Avoid WooCommerce Checkout Billing form to overwrite default Wordpress user data

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout, user-data

in the database we have **metauser** table that contain:
The **`first_name`** and **`last_name`** fields

Those are the default Wordpress first and last name.

And also we have: 
The **`billing_first_name`**  and **`billing_last_name`**.

now when user fill out the billing form and proceed the checkout process,
Woocommerce update both fields with the new values from billing name fields
(the default ones).

I have tried many things used actions like:

```
woocommerce_before_checkout_billing_form
```

or

```
woocommerce_after_checkout_billing_form
```

Also tried to update meta with:

```
update_user_meta()
```

But it's not working.

I want it to not overwrite the default first_name and last_name,
but keep the new values only in billing_first_name and billing_last_name

I think the default process is like that 
https://gist.github.com/claudiosanches/ae9a8b496c431bec661b69ef73f1a087

Any help on this please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The way is to use a custom funtion hooked in **`woocommerce_checkout_update_customer`** action hook:

```
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_update_customer','custom_checkout_update_customer', 10, 2 );
function custom_checkout_update_customer( $customer, $data ){

    if ( ! is_user_logged_in() || is_admin() ) return;

    // Get the user ID
    $user_id = $customer->get_id();

    // Get the default wordpress first name and last name (if they exist)
    $user_first_name = get_user_meta( $user_id, 'first_name', true );
    $user_last_name = get_user_meta( $user_id, 'last_name', true );

    if( empty( $user_first_name ) || empty( $user_last_name ) ) return;

    // We set the values by defaul worpress ones, before it's saved to DB
    $customer->set_first_name( $user_first_name );
    $customer->set_last_name( $user_last_name );
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*

Tested and works in WooCommerce 3+

Comment: Is there any way to store Billing data in a new database table ?

Comment: @YahyaEssam, You should better create instead custom related user meta data, it will be more easy and affordable… don't you think?

Comment: Why would WooCommerce change this?  They have billing_first_name, billing_last_name for a reason, why mess with Wordpress' first/last_name metas.  Silly.  Thanks for the snippet, it works.